# Как сделать так, чтобы декоратор @bot.message_handler прекращал свою работу?

Tags: python-3.x, telebot, декоратор

Запланировал написать викторину в телеграм боте. Мне нужно, чтобы после того, как человек написал правильный ответ на первый вопрос, задекорированная функция прекращала работать, а начинала работать другая функция. По логике программы вроде все верно, но он продолжает обрабатывать именно первый декоратор. Что подскажите?

Вот конструктор самого кода:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    murkup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Начать!', callback_data="start")
    murkup.add(button1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, {0.first_name}!\n"
                                  "Начинаем квест!".format(message.from_user), reply_markup= 
murkup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def start(call):
    if call.data == "start":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'вот первый вопрос')

        @bot.message_handler()
        def answer (message):
            mes = message.text
            mes = mes.lower()
            if mes == "правильный ответ":
                murkup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Следующий вопрос', сallback_data="second_question")
                murkup.add(button1)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Это правильный ответ!', reply_markup= murkup)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Неправильно! думай еще!')

    elif call.data == "second_question":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Вот тут второй вопрос')

        @bot.message_handler()
        def two_answer (message):
            mes = message.text
            mes = mes.lower()
            if mes == "правильный ответ":
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Это правильный ответ!')
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Неправильно! думай еще!')


bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Comment: Черт возьми кто этот человек? Кто?! Кто заставляет вас всех это делать? Зачем вы вставляете хендлер внутрь другого хендлера?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1421179/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5/1421215#1421215 смотрите

Comment: Чем вам не вариант? Никаких внутренних хендлеров! Красиво и просто. И ваша проблема тоже решиться

Comment: @oleksandrigo В таком варианте пользователь может отправить данные которые вы не ожидаете. Например вы спрашиваете имя, а он отправляет число. При этом программа продолжит работу.  Лучше использовать `FSM`, например [вот](https://github.com/devnowcommit/FSMTelegramBotAPI). При таком методе,можно проверять входящие данные.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо вложенных в друг друга хендлеров, вам нужно использовать функцию `register_next_step_handler(message, next_handler)`.

[Вот отличное описание данной функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243528/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-register-next-step-handler-%D0%B2-pytelegrambotapi)